# AngularJS - What is the correct syntax to initialize a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax

I have been following a few tutorials about AngularJS and I noticed that there are multiple methods to initialize a Controller.

For example, the following code is based on the AngularJS documentation:

```
angular.module('todoList', [])
.controller('todoListCtrl', ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        ...
    }
]);
```

However, this code also works:

```
angular.module('todoList', [])
.controller('todoListCtrl',
    function ($scope) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Is one method preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second syntax is not minification safe.  Once you minify, the uglifier will rename `$scope` meaning that it will not be able to be injected properly by the AngularJS injector, since the injector uses name-matching to identify which depedency to resolve.

The first syntax was added to fix this issue and is the syntax you should use for production applications.

Comment: I never heard the name `uglifier` ,  that is probably the tool that got to some of my ex's

Comment: Closure, Grunt/gulp packages, RequireJS, Webpack...they all have an "uglifier" that renames the codebase to compact it.   For instance: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify